# How to return all the record if condition variable is empty?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have articles and users collection. `userId` is in articles model with data type `Schema.ObjectId`. In a view, I show all the articles and on top I am showing dropdown of all users to filter the articles. If dropdown's placeholder is selected all articles will be return and if any user is selected then that user's articles will be return. My API code is given below. When dropdown's placeholder is selected the `UserId` query string will have blank value otherwise it will have any exising user's ID.

```
exports.list = function (req, res) {
    var userId = '';
    if (req.query.UserId) {
        userId = req.query.UserId;   
    }
    Article.find({userId: userId}).exec(function (err, articles) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(400).send({
                message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
            });
        } else {
            res.json(articles);
        }
    });
};
```

Now the issue is I can't return all the articles because when query string parameter is blank, the query tries to find those articles which has `userId` as blank. So how can I skip condition checking if condition parameter is empty or null?

I want to do same as given below, which is C# LINQ query.

```
var userId = <value from query string>;
var lstArticles = dbContext.Articles.Where(objArticle => (userId == '' || objArticle.userId == userId));
```

Comment: @chridam sorry my bad, it was typo, corrected it.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the **[`req.query`](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.query)** object since it is an object containing a property for each query string parameter in the route. If there is no query string, it is the empty object, `{}`.

E.g

```
// GET /api/articles?userId=57ac922c457312e0e5c1ad6c
req.query.userId
// => "57ac922c457312e0e5c1ad6c"

// GET /api/articles?userId=57ac922c457312e0e5c1ad6c
req.query
// => { "userId": "57ac922c457312e0e5c1ad6c" }  

// GET /api/articles
req.query.userId
// => undefined

// GET /api/articles
req.query
// => {}
```

Hence

```
exports.list = function (req, res) {
    var q = req.query;
    if (req.query.UserId) {
        q.user = req.query.UserId; // because you have a different key in your database  
    }
    Article.find(q).exec(function (err, articles) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(400).send({
                message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
            });
        } else {
            res.json(articles);
        }
    });
};
```

---

**--EDIT--**

Since you corrected the typo in your question on the `user` key in `{ user: userId }`, you can simply use the **[`req.query`](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.query)** object as your mongoose find query document, as long as the properties (**[`req.query`](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.query)** parameters) match those in the database's document fields:

**Route**

```
/api/articles                         → Article.find({ })
/api/articles?userId=foo              → Article.find({ userId: 'foo' })
/api/articles?title=bar               → Article.find({ title: 'bar' })
/api/articles?userId=foo&title=bar    → Article.find({ userId: 'foo', title: 'bar' })
```

**API**

```
exports.list = function (req, res) {        
    Article.find(req.query).exec(function (err, articles) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(400).send({
                message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
            });
        } else {
            res.json(articles);
        }
    });
};
```

The above approach means any **[`req.query`](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.query)** parameter passed in will be used as the `find()` query so its recommened to filter **[`req.query`](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.query)** before using it in the `find()` method so it only contains fields that are defined in your schema.

For example, suppose the **[`req.query`](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.query)** object has a `user` parameter and yet you have defined a `userId` field in your schema, you can filter it as:

```
var q = {};
if (req.query.user) {
    q.userId = req.query.user; // because you have a different key in your database  
}
Article.find(q).exec(callback);
```

Comment: To go with your solution I have to keep query string param keys same as mongodb path with *case sensitivity*, am I right?

Comment: Correct and that means any `req.query` parameter passed in will be used as the `find()` query so its recommened to filter `req.query` before using it in the `find()` method so it only contains fields that are defined in your schema.

Comment: But still the empty query string problem is not solved. If I request to `/api/articles?userId=foo&title=` it will search for article with blank title.

Comment: You then need to filter the `req.query` object, check for blank values for each key and remove the key from the query object if it has a blank value before using it in your `find()` method.